# Bug in Programming Interviews Exposed?

Tags: c++

I could not find an errata for the 2nd edition of this book. My question concerns the if-statement in the following piece of code.

```
void removeHead (Node ** head) {
  Node * temp;
  if (!(*head)) {
    temp = (*head)->next;
    delete *head;
    *head = temp;
  }
}
```

So I understand that the point of the if-statement is to check if the Node is null. However by adding an additional "!" to the evaluation, wouldn't this negate the false value of null? Would it be correct to change it to something like:

```
if (*head) { ... }
```

Also if anyone knows where I can find an official errata for the 2nd edition that would be great.

Thanks,

Sam

Comment: The question is rather... why would anyone write code like this in C++? Node should be a class and the linked list should be another class with head as private variable and remove..something should be a public function.

Comment: Official Errata http://www.wiley.com/legacy/compbooks/programminginterview/errata.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The book is a little flawed in that it first claims that there are no problems with `*head` as an input, and then further develops to say you should really pass in `**head`, and then says you should check `*head`. You really need to check `*head` AND `head`.

As for `if (!(*head))`, if `*head` is NULL, this would be `if (!0)` which would be true. Then we try `(0)->next` and die. Definitely a mistake.

Comment: Thanks this was the answer I was looking for. At least two people have stated that !(*head) is equal to *head != NULL, which is what I was confused by.

Comment: @Sam If they said that, they're wrong. !x is equivalent to (x == 0) for any x.

Comment: I'd say more than a little flawed by the looks of it :)

Answer (score 2):

The code as shown is incorrect:  if `*head` is null, you dereference it, which is certainly incorrect.

Comment: I don't see a dereference of `*head` (i.e., `**head`), just a dereference of `head`.  The negation is the problem here.

Comment: @Ed S.:  `if(!(*head))` tests whether `*head` is null; if it is null, the `if` block is entered.  The first line in the `if` block has `(*head)->next`, which dereferences `(*head)`.  That's what I thought I said in the answer?  Maybe I was unclear?

Comment: @Ed A dereference of x is not "i.e." *x ... x->y is also a dereference of x, and there's certainly one here.

Comment: Sorry, I just misunderstood you (probably read too quickly).  We are saying the same thing.

Comment: @Jim Balter:  I know, I was only looking at the condition, just read too quickly.  Like I said, the negation in the if statement is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

`head` being a pointer to a pointer to a Node, you not only need to check that the second level pointer is not null, but also that the first-level pointer is not null, which you could do by adding the condition `head != NULL`.

Also, as you correctly pointed out in your comment, the condition `!(*head)` is actually the opposite of what you want to do (it would be `true` when `*head` is NULL). Use rather `*head != NULL`, which is more readable, and less error-prone.

Comment: But isn't "!(*head)" different from "*head != NULL"? Suppose *head is NULL... wouldn't that mean "!(*head) evaluates to true and "*head != NULL" evaluates to false?

Answer (score 1):

Doubt, Is the value of NULL considered as zero irrespective of platforms???

I doubt it , I guess comparison should always be wrt

```
if( * head != NULL ) 
 {  ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

****head->*head->head**. And when you do, `*head`, you are dereferencing to the mid location. And when that is NULL, `if` loop is entered. So, if it is NULL, how can it point to `head` and ask for a member variable `next`. This should work, as you suggested -

```
if((*head) != NULL )
{
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the !

Then change delete into free and retag C